# react: "Can only update a mounted or mounting component."

Tags: reactjs

The `setState` call in question is working despite the warning. The warning only occurs after the component on which I am calling `setState` has been removed, and then rerendered. Why am I getting this warning *when the component is already mounted*?

```
<div id="contentArea">

     {this.state.activePlugin?this.state.activePlugin.render():null}

</div>
```

the render method returns a react element:

```
render(){ 

    return <DatasetsList />;

}
```

`state.activePlugin` is set to null and the component containing the jsx code above is rerendered, this is how removing the 'activePlugin' happens. When `render` is called again and returns the `<DatasetsList />` for the second time, subsequent clicks inside the component produce this warning, despite the fact that the `setState` calls they initiate in fact work as expected.

In other words, the warning appears to be misleading, as the code is working as expected.

```
 componentDidMount() { 
        this.unsubscribe = this.props.store.listen(s=>{
          this.setState(s);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet to illustrate ?

Comment: but you failed to add any code which calls `setState`

Comment: Added, though not sure how it will help you.

Comment: Warning appears to be correct it seems since parent node with `id#contentArea` is still present in dom.

Comment: Actually the answer was in that last bit of code. The old instance was still listening as unsubscribe had not been called. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/taylorallred/69z2wepo/29874/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      activePlugin: Plugin
    }
  },

  togglePlugin: function() {
    this.setState({
      activePlugin: this.state.activePlugin ? null : Plugin
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div >
      < div onClick = {
        this.togglePlugin
      } > Hello {
        this.props.name
      } < /div> < div > {
        this.state.activePlugin ? < Plugin / > : null
      } < /div> < /div>;
  }
});

var Plugin = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( < MyComponent / > );
  }
});

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return {a: 1};
  },
    componentDidMount:function(){
     window.setInterval(function(that){that.setState({a: that.state.a++})}, 2000, this);
  },

    render: function() {
        var a = this.state.a;
    return <div > MyComponent { a }< /div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < Hello name = "World" / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

It's probably because your component is receiving updates when it's not rendered and that component is trying to render because it's state changed. See the fiddle. Click to remove the component and you'll get that error in the console.

Comment: Already read that one. It's not related - my component is mounted.

Comment: Post your code then, it's too vague to know otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The warning was referring to the old unmounted instance of my component which was still listening to the store, as shown in the question. Simply unsubscribing from the store inside `componentWillUnmount` solved the issue.

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribe();
    }
```